# How to open programatically a Form for selected SpreadSheet in Google Docs?

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a form that populates the spreadsheet. If someone puts wrong data i need to correct it in spreadsheet. But i have a lots of columns. I want to edit it with the form that user uses. How to open a form for a selected row in Google Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes from apps script you can use getEditResponseUrl() ([link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#getEditResponseUrl()))

Exemple of code

```
var line = 5; //Line in the spreadsheet you want url
var form = FormApp.openByUrl("URLOfForm");
var reps = form.getResponses();
Logger.log(reps[(line-2)].getEditResponseUrl());
```

Stéphane

Comment: Thanks, it seems what i need. I've created a new script, put the code there, but it tells me i don't have permission to openByUrl. How to fix it?

Comment: You have to change URLOfForm by an url of a form you can modify